# UrlGenerationException: Missing required parameters for [Route: topics.update] [URI: topics/{topic}]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravelcollective, laravel-form

I'm getting this error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: topics.update] [URI: topics/{topic}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\phpboards\resources\views\topics\edit.blade.php)
```

This is link that will take user to edit:

```
<a href="/boards/topics/edit/{{$topic->id}}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
```

This is the controller for edit:

```
$topic = Topic::find($id);
return view('topics.edit')->with('topic', $topic);
```

This is the Route:

```
Route::get('/boards/topics/edit/{id}', 'TopicController@edit');
```

This is the form for edit:

```
<div class="container">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TopicController@update', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
            {{ Form::text('title', $topic->topic_title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title of the Post']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('desc', 'Desc') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('desc', $topic->topic_body, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Description of the Post']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

What i have done wrong here??

Comment: @ParantapParashar But for what?? and for which controller??

Comment: There are so many errors in your code.

Comment: I think you must put here your update method and Route too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TopicController@update', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

use

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('topics.update', $topic->id), 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

because for your route you need to pass id of topic you want to update. Also it's more reasonable to use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes) instead Controller@method notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's admit your `update()` method is already implemented on your TopicController.

First you need to declare another route:

```
Route::put('/boards/topics/edit/{id}', 'TopicController@update');
//     ^^^
```

then change your Form opening by this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['TopicController@update', $topic->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
//                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^
```

it should works.

Comment: are you sure you have modified your `Form::open` parameters ? try this command: `artisan route:clear && artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Above solution worked. I was not passing the id of the post. That was creating the error.

Comment: Yep I saw it, that's why I suggested you that. I really suggest you to name your route and use `put` instead of `post` for updating resource. (according to RESTful v3)